# How to scroll to newly added row in a table automatically when we click on add row button in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Table component of Material UI to create table in react. I am performing CURD operations on Table. In a table at a time only six rows are visible.If we want to see more records, need to scroll down and see remaining rows. The problem is when I click on add row button, new row is adding but, the focus is not moving to newly added row(It should scroll down automatically). In first column of table row, created text field. When I add row It should focus that text field.I tried by using focus() method, but it didn't work.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please share the code we cant blindly answer It does not help community

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Having the same problem, can't find any solution....

Answer (score 0):

`scrollIntoView()` is enough to scroll to any element.
I created a demo for you. Hope it can help.

Please see this demo in full page mode.

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  rows = new Array(50).fill(0);
  lastRowRef;
  
  render(){
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.scrollToLastRow}>scroll to last row</button>
        <div>
          <table>
          {
            this.rows.map((row,i)=>
              <tr key={i} ref={(i===this.rows.length-1)? (r) => this.lastRowRef=r: null}>
                <td>{i+1}</td>
                <td>Row {i+1}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          }
          </table>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  
  scrollToLastRow=()=>{
    if(this.lastRowRef){
      this.lastRowRef.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is not what he is after though. He is asking how to scroll to a newly added row. E.g in your example, replace "Scroll to last row" button with "Add new row" button which adds a new row at the bottom. Then scrolls to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code that I made:

**Add this function above render() method:**

```
addRowAndScroll = () => {
    var tableBody = document.getElementById('someTableBody');
    var tableBodyLength = tableBody.childNodes.length;
    tableBody.innerHTML += `<tr><td>test</td></tr>`;
    tableBody = document.getElementById('someTableBody');
    tableBody.childNodes[tableBodyLength].scrollIntoView();
}
```

**Here's the HTML. Notice that on button click `addRowAndScroll` is being called. This will add row to the table and then scroll the view to that added row.**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ ()=> this.addRowAndScroll() }>Add Row</button>   
            <table>
                <thead><tr><th>Company</th></tr></thead>
                <tbody id="someTableBody">
                    <tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Ernst Handel</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Island Trading</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This is merely a "react" way. You are manipulating the DOM directly which is allowed in react but not recommended at all AFAIK